# Stripe invoice.payment_succeeded webhook is triggered multiple times

Tags: java, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe (test mode) to develop the payment module in my application. I have done the following,

1. Subscribing a customer to an existing plan created in stripe using Customer.create(customerParams). Which I understand that it will create a customer, subscribe to the plan, creates the invoice, charges the invoice.
2. I have added a webhook for invoice.payment_succeeded (paymentSuccess) and invoice.payment_failure (paymentFailure) only. Created a webhook in my application.

I get the following,

1. My paymentSuccess webhook is called successfully after the Customer.create(customerParams) is called, using which I can retrieve event, invoice, charge and customer details to process it in my application. The paid flag is set to true.
2. This webhook is called more than once (even more than 3 times) in a specific interval (around 30 mins or so), with different invoice id, customer id, charge id.

My questions:

1. Why there is a multiple webhook call for the same event?
2. If it is a retry for the failed payment, actually there is no failed payment. The call was always for invoice.payment_succeeded.
3. Even if the event is repeated, why the customer_id, invoice_id are different each time as it is supposed to be the same since the payment has been done only once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If the customer ID, invoice ID and charge ID are different, then it's not the same event.

You probably have multiple customers with subscriptions set up on your account.

Stripe will send an [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) event each time payment succeeds for *any* invoice.

If you have multiple customers with subscriptions, Stripe will automatically create an invoice for each of them at the start of each billing periods, and attempt payment for these invoices approximately one hour after creation.

You can look up the [`attempt_count`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object-attempt_count) attribute on any [invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object) to know whether this is the first payment attempt or not for a given invoice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually there are no other customer subscription to that specific plan. So, to clarify,
1. I have a plan "basic"

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually there are no other customer subscriptions. 

So, to clarify,
1. I have a plan "basic"
2. Subscribed 2 customers "alex and john" to that plan on different dates (1st Jan and 15th Nov).
3. So, on 1st of Jan, invoice for alex is generated and payment will be attempted, invoice.payment_succeeded hook will be triggered. So, invoice.payment_succeeded hook handler will be called once.
4. So, on 1st of Jan, would invoice.payment_succeeded hook for john also be triggered? If so, why is that when it is supposed to be only on 1st Nov?

Comment: Hi Karikalan. You should write to Stripe's support about this, so we can take a look at your account directly and offer a clear explanation of what's going on. You can reach out to support using the form at https://support.stripe.com/email.

Comment: I have successfully implemented webhook and catch the webhook event to manipulate the data. I want to get the details like subscription id, customer id but I cannot get it by directly accessing the attributes through objects. How do I do that

Answer (score 0):

**Did you return status 200 at the end of the event?**

This event can also be fired several times for not being successfully executed. Stripe will try to complete the request so, there should be return status to notify stripe whether it is completed or failed.